# Failing to connect to mongo when deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I am trying to deploy my node app to Heroku.

I have added the MLab MongoDB add on and have set the config variable

```
$ heroku config
=== thevoyageapp Config Vars
MONGODB_URI:            mongodb://heroku_f80ngvbz:btt04p7erog80@ds.mlab.com:11/herokgvbz
```

And have added the process.env.MONGODB_URI to my mongo connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let url = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/trip';
mongoose.connect(url, { useMongoClient: true });
```

But I still get this error:

```
2018-01-23T06:00:15.722831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/index.js`
2018-01-23T06:00:17.808211+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb://heroku_f80ngvbz:btt04p7erog80cot3ufp1@ds.mlab.com:11/heroku_f80ngvbz
2018-01-23T06:00:17.807864+00:00 app[web.1]: listening on port 3000         ^
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835657+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835658+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835659+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835663+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835660+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835664+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:189:49)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835662+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835664+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835665+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835666+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.835668+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2018-01-23T06:00:17.940249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-01-23T06:00:17.926212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: From the logs, it appears that it's failing to get the value from process.env.MONGODB_URI and falling back to localhost.

Comment: Hi, you've posted the username and password to your database in your connection string. Please make sure to reset your database password as soon as possible. (In the future, you should make sure to redact your username and password from the connection string before publicly posting it)

Comment: And I agree with Doug. Perhaps you have not committed the recent changes where you set the url to `process.env.MONGODB_URI` or you connect to localhost elsewhere in your code?

Comment: If you look at line 2 of the error I do a console log of process.env.MONGODB_URI and it shows the correct mongodb uri.

Comment: Your code isn't connecting using that URI. It's trying to connect to localhost. Can you paste your whole server/index.js file?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. In my server/index.js I had a reference to localhost in the session / MongoStore

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

It is highly possible that you forget to whitelist the server IP to access MongoDB database. You can whitelist the IP at MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: The code is trying to connect to localhost, not to remote database.